# Copying files from a dependency JAR into build directory with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency, whose JAR has the following files:

```
~ git:master ❯❯❯ jar tf `find ~/.gradle/caches -name "myorg-*.jar"`
thrift-include-dir/
thrift-include-dir/shared/
thrift-include-dir/shared/types/
thrift-include-dir/shared/types/criteria.thrift
thrift-include-dir/shared/types/stagefetchtype.thrift
```

I want these files to be present in a directory when a certain task (generateThriftSources) runs, because I need to be able to do this in the parent project:

```
include "shared/types/stagefetchtype.thrift"
```

Can I copy the directory from the classpath into a specific build directory subfolder, like `build/thrift-include-dir`?

Comment: Yes, you can copy it. Why not?

Comment: How would I go about writing the task? As in, how do I refer to a certain directory inside a JAR?

Comment: You can do a copy task and use FileTree to read the contents of the jar file.  Some examples in https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html 15.4. Using the contents of an archive as a file tree